# Invalidate Shopware 6 page cache on entity update via API

Tags: caching, shopware6

We created a custom CMS element which displays entries which are managed via API.

Now when entries are updated and Shopware 6 runs ins production mode, the changes are not reflected on the page. I believe this is due to the page cache. (`APP_ENV=prod`)

What do we have to do to invalidate the cache automatically?

I checked [the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/caches), but did not find the necessary information.

For the product box it works: When I place a product CMS element on the main page and change the product, the page is updated when I reload in the browser.
I was expecting to find some hint in `\Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Cms\ProductBoxCmsElementResolver` but there are no cache tags or something like this added there.

EDIT: Actually I was a bit inaccurate. The page I have lists the entities, and it is a category page.

So I believe I have too hook into `CategoryRouteCacheTagsEvent`.

For testing I hard-coded into:

`\Shopware\Core\Content\Category\SalesChannel\CachedCategoryRoute::extractProductIds`

```
    $slots = $page->getElementsOfType('jobs');
    /** @var CmsSlotEntity $slot */
    foreach ($slots as $slot) {
        $box = $slot->getData();
        $ids = array_merge($ids, $box['jobs']->getIds());
    }
```

But this does not yet work.

PS: Also I noticed some code duplication in the core in `\Shopware\Core\Content\Category\SalesChannel\CachedCategoryRoute::extractProductIds` and `\Shopware\Core\Content\LandingPage\SalesChannel\CachedLandingPageRoute::extractIds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers of dneustadt and Uwe, as for the job listings I solved it like with this two subscribes. I do not need any single ID here, because the full listing page has to be invalidated in case a job is deleted or added. This is why I went with the `any-jobs` tag:

```
use Shopware\Core\Content\Category\Event\CategoryRouteCacheTagsEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CacheKeyEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
    return [
        CategoryRouteCacheTagsEvent::class => 'generateTags'
    ];
    }

    public function generateTags(CategoryRouteCacheTagsEvent $event): void
    {
    $page = $event->getResponse()->getCategory()->getCmsPage();
    $slots = $page->getElementsOfType('jobs');
    if (!empty($slots)) {
        $event->setTags(
            array_merge($event->getTags(), ['any-jobs'])
        );
    }
    }
}
```

and

```
class CacheInvalidationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private CacheInvalidator $cacheInvalidator;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
    return [
        EntityWrittenContainerEvent::class => 'invalidateJobs'
    ];
    }

    public function __construct(CacheInvalidator $cacheInvalidator)
    {
    $this->cacheInvalidator = $cacheInvalidator;
    }


    public function invalidateJobs(EntityWrittenContainerEvent $event): void
    {
    if (!empty($event->getPrimaryKeys(\ApplicationManagement\Core\Content\JobAd\JobAdDefinition::ENTITY_NAME))) {
        $this->cacheInvalidator->invalidate(
            ['any-jobs']
        );
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Cache\CacheInvalidationSubscriber` listens to a lot of events, including indexer and entity-written events. This in turn uses the `CacheInvalidator` to invalidate cached data based on tags/cache keys.

You should be able to add invalidation based on your own entity in a similar fashion.

For this to work with a custom entity, you will probably have to tag any cache entries with something you can generate on invalidation. For CMS pages, I would probably start with the `CachedLandingPageRoute` as a reference.

Comment: I found https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e8ed81e0332a7dc628dc4b8f5115df3a593d282e/src/Core/Content/LandingPage/SalesChannel/CachedLandingPageRoute.php#L122 so I guess I have to listen to that event to add tags with my entity IDs?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should have a look at the [`CacheInvalidationSubscriber`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/f16f8398b9e562a8c110f2e121ff559a691f6cb0/src/Core/Framework/Adapter/Cache/CacheInvalidationSubscriber.php) and its [service definition](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/67b3bac9b2aae79094db51859cfe9ab887144103/src/Core/Framework/DependencyInjection/services.xml#L648). You can see that there are already a bunch of events that are dispatched when write operations to certain entities occur. When you then look at the respective handler you can see how it invalidates the cache for whatever kind of routes it should affect.

When you speak of entries I assume you implemented your own custom entities for use in your CMS element? If that is the case just replicate the listener for your own entities. Otherwise you'll have to look for another event that is dispatched once you save your changes and then invalidate the cache likewise.

Comment: Yes we have a custom entity, will try